# MS SQL Server: Logic to find out groups of all dependent records from table having source and destinations items

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursion

I am using MS SQL Server DB. I have a specific need to find out groups of interdependent items. Visualize below a scenario where we have two items in each row, one is source item and other is destination item. Any item can be source of any item, and same for destination as well. We have two column in the table, 'Source' and 'Destination'. Let's consider 10 values in the table as below:

```
Source | Destination
A | B
B | C
C | D
E | A
D | E
X | Y
Y | Z
Z | X
P | Q
R | S
```

My requirement is to get distinct groups of items with Source and destination. Meaning, my query should return below result with 4 rows (grouped items in comma separated form):

```
RowNum| Result
1| A,B,C,D,E
2| X,Y,Z
3| P,Q
4| R,S
```

Here, the level of hierarchy can be upto n number. In my example, I kept the first group of 5 items (A to B, B to C, C to D, D to E and E to A - Means 5 different items are involved in this group). But the data may have more items as well, in single group. Also, cyclical records are possible (X to , Y to Z and Z to X)

I can achieve this using nested WHILE Loops. But, as we have thousands of records, the nested WHILE Loop scripts takes too much time to execute. I am iterating one loop on each record of the table and then there is an inner loop which will take outer loop's record and will compare it with all other records.

Can anybody suggest a better way or algorithm to achieve this?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to solve this in SQL you need to be more specific regarding the database you are using, i.e. postgres, mysql, oracle, etc...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: We are using Microsoft SQL Database.